# What hashing algorithm does Dropbox use as file identifier?

Tags: hash, dropbox-api

I'm reading through Dropbox API v2 documentation and it says that [every file and folder has an ID](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation). It looks something like this: `"id:a4ayc_80_OEAAAAAAAAAXw"`.

Does anyone know how they generate these IDs?
Is there any way to get SHA hash of files from Dropbox?

Comment: I don't think that this kind of implementation information is easily divulgated. If you ever find how they implement it, chances are you are going to have a bad weekend.

Comment: Dropbox doesn't have any documentation on how these IDs are generated. Your app should just consider them opaque identifiers. The Dropbox API also doesn't currently expose any sort of file hashes, but we'll consider this a feature request.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252508/search-dropbox-or-google-drive-by-file-hash-or-file-metadata/42935650#42935650 for an update.